# How do I pipe output to date -d "value"?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, date

I have a date like `2014-01-30 05:04:27 GMT`, and if I run `date -d "2014-01-30 05:04:27 GMT"`, the output is in my server's timezone (`Thu Jan 30 16:04:27 EST 2014`).

With the use of grep and cut, I have extracted the date in GMT from a file. However, I am struggling to then convert this into my local time.

For example:

```
grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'['
```

Output: `2014-01-30 05:04:27 GMT`

What can I add on the end, to pass that output to `date -d`?

Attempted:

```
grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[' | date -d
```

```
grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[' | date
```

```
grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[' | date -d "$1"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
gmt="$(grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[')"
date -d "$gmt"
```

Or, if you prefer the pipeline format:

```
grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[' | { read gmt ; date -d "$gmt" ; }
```

The problem is that `date` does not use stdin.  Thus, we have to capture the stdin into a variable (called `gmt` here) and then supply that on the command line to `date`.

Sample output from the second approach:

```
$ echo  "2014-01-30 05:04:27 GMT" | { read gmt ; date -d "$gmt" ; }
Wed Jan 29 21:04:27 PST 2014
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! Also appreciate you explaining the reason behind why it wasn't working.

Comment: I have used the -f option, but your answer with the pipeline format is very elegant!

Answer (score 29):

If you're using GNU date from a sufficiently recent coreutils, there's `date -f`, from the help screen:

```
-f, --file=DATEFILE       like --date once for each line of DATEFILE
```

So your attempt 4 could have been:

```
$ grep "something" logfile.txt | grep "Succeeded" | cut -f1 -d'[' | date -f -
```

the last `-` stands for stdin.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is it possible to compare the output of the above command to a particular date.  Eg. I need to list all dates older than "Wed Jan 30 21:04:27 PST 2014"

Comment: @Manu not per se, [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) have `dategrep` for that specific use case.

Comment: This is so much easier! If only I could read I might have found this in he man page.

Comment: how do you pair this with timestamp parsing, e.g. `date --date @<timestamp>`

Answer (score 3):

Just use **stdin** as **file**:

```
command | date --file=-
```

Comment: Please add an explanation *why* this works, preferably with documentation links.