# one-liner to put two commands on same line, from the multiline output of `find... | sort... | cut ...`

Tags: linux, bash, find, sorting

This is a continuation of [recursively sort files with string "SENT_" somewhere in filename by the substring immediately after SENT_, and then display them. Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1563907/recursively-sort-files-with-string-sent-somewhere-in-filename-by-the-substrin) as I thought it was better to separate out the questions...

What I was helped with there gave me an order (by the seconds date, i.e. $(date +%s) as a substring in the file) such as,

```
SENT_1593129066_edb8ff571bc493cb700c3ae6ccfa5869__HDR.tex_
SENT_1593129143_db550b5fa1578ba40c952dac10b9b779__HDR.tex_
SENT_1593129190_00d69a5407bb6f394609f1d387573e2e__HDR.tex_
```

and my goal is to, one the same line, put in parentheses the 'proper date' at the end, i.e.

```
SENT_1593129066_edb8ff571bc493cb700c3ae6ccfa5869__HDR.tex_ (June 20, 2020 15:32:33)
SENT_1593129143_db550b5fa1578ba40c952dac10b9b779__HDR.tex_ (July 21, 2020 19:44:02)
SENT_1593129190_00d69a5407bb6f394609f1d387573e2e__HDR.tex_ (Aug 22, 2020 04:43:38)
```

(dates and format are made up)

So I did this to get the `$(date +%s)` part,

```
gg () { find . -type f -name "*"$@"*" -printf '%f\n' |  sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | cut -d'_' -f 2  ;  }
gg SENT

1593129066
1593129143
1593129190
```

where the `cut` is the only thing new from the linked page.

The 1st problem **was** getting it into `date -d ???` but luckily I found:
[How do I pipe output to date -d "value"?](https://superuser.com/questions/711017/how-do-i-pipe-output-to-date-d-value)

which said `date` needed a variable. So I would try this:

```
gg () { find . -type f -name "*"$@"*" -printf '%f\n' | \  
 sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | \
 tee 
  >(echo "<FILENAME_LIKE_'SENT_1593130907_....tex'>" ) 
  >(cut -d'_' -f 2 | { read gmt ; date -d "$gmt"; } )  ; 
}
```

---

*START OF QUESTION*

My idea was to assemble the 2 parts on one line, ie for `SENT_1593129066_edb8ff571bc493cb700c3ae6ccfa5869__HDR.tex_` (1st part - **don't have this yet**) and `(June 20, 2020 15:32:33)` (2nd part) by using `tee` to pipe the output from `sort` to both;

1. printing/echo the original filename, ie the first part, and
2. the date in parenthesis, e.g. `(June 20, 2020 15:32:33)`

This idea, `tee >(what_to_do) >(another_thing_to_do)` came from:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/833070/how-would-i-pass-the-output-of-one-command-to-multiple-commands

and seems to put both parts on the same line. If not, I **wonder** if I'll need something like the following wrapped around the `tee`...? But right now it only does the 'first' `>(echo...)` part once...

The idea to put them on the same line, which I was thinking of using `{ echo "The quick"; echo "brown fox"; } | tr "\n" " "` from

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871534/concatenate-in-bash-the-output-of-two-commands-without-newline-character?noredirect=1&lq=1

---

**SUMMARY**

So I need to

1. do the '`echo`' part to recover the whole filename (preferably with the directories) and `(date +%s)` substring, eg `~/dir_A/dir2/SENT_1593129066_asdfasdfasdf_asdf.tex`, and
2. put them on one line, for each file found by `find`.

This will then be the end of the function I wanted.

---

**EDIT**

This only worked once; (I don't know about `paste` but it would be better, but not necessary, to have more common tools...)

```
gg () { find . -type f -name "*"$@"*" -printf '%f\n' | \
 sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | \
 paste  
  <(echo "<FILENAME_LIKE_'SENT_1593130907_....tex'>" ) 
  <(cut -d'_' -f 2 | { read gmt ; date -d @"$gmt"; } )  ; 
}
```

Trying to fix it so far has failed;

```
gg () { find . -type f -name "*"$@"*" -printf '%f\n' |  \
 sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | \ 
 xargs -I'{}' paste  
  <(echo "<FILENAME_LIKE_'SENT_1593130907_....tex'>" ) 
  <(cut -d'_' -f 2 | { read gmt ; date -d @"$gmt"; } )  ; 
}
```

Comment: Side note: `find … -name "*"$@"*"` is either a bug (if you don't have a clue) or bad practice (if you do). `-name` needs *exactly* one argument. `$@` can expand to multiple arguments even if double-quoted. You should use (double-quoted) `$1`, unless you consciously intend to enhance the expression of `find` via arguments of `gg` (e.g. `gg foo -links 1 -name bar`). But even then `$@` should be double-quoted.

Comment: I don't recall why that was like that haha but from your attention I read more about it. Seems if I do want 1 argument though I would use `"$*"`... or what I am now using `ff () { find . -type f -name "$1" -printf '%f\n' | sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 |  ( while read LINE; do TS=$( echo "$LINE"| cut -d_ -f 2 ); TSD=$( date -d @$TS ); printf "%s (%s)\n" "$LINE" "$TSD" ; done; ); }` as I will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is a programming language ( please read `man bash` ) , so you can do a loop.

Example 1 :

```
find . -type f -name 'SENT*' -printf '%f\n' | \
   sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | \
   ( 
     while read LINE ; 
     do 
       TS=$( echo "$LINE"| cut -d_ -f 2 ) ; 
       TSD=$( date  -d @$TS ) ;
       printf "%s (%s)\n"  "$LINE" "$TSD"  ;
     done
    )
```

Example 2 ( reported by another user ) :

```
find . -type f -name 'SENT*' -printf '%f\n' | \
   sort -t'_' -k2.1,2.10 | \
   awk -F_ '{print $0" ("strftime("%c",$2)")"}'
```

Comment: Or using another 'programming' language available almost everywhere bash is: `... | awk -F_ '{print $0" ("strftime("%c",$2)")"}'` (other formats available per manual)

Comment: I actually know a little about functions and for-loops in bash (and have crammed too much in my .bashrc actually - where this will go) though I have much to learn - the scripting language guides are great but its a slow process :) https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/